# Laravel auth middleware not remembering me

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5, remember-me

I can't seem to get [remember me](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#remembering-users) to work.

Here's what I'm trying:

1. If I check the "Remember Me" checkbox on my login page and then log in, the `remember_token` column my database gets filled in
2. I then use Chrome to delete the `laravel_session` cookie to emulate a session expiring [image]
3. I click another link on my webpage, and I immediately get logged out

I expect Laravel to use this `remember_me_XXX` token to log me back in, but it's not happening.

I'm not sure where to look to debug this. Presumably it's handled by the "auth" middleware, but that just takes me through a rabbit trail of facades. Searching for "remember_web" turns up 0 results, so I don't even know where that cookie is coming from.

So my question is,

1. What do I have to do/implement to get Laravel to use the remember me token to log me back in,
2. OR, where in the Laravel source code is this cookie read and used, so that I can debug this?

Comment: I found something in `\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::user` -- investigating now

Comment: `\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::validRecaller` is returning false because the remember me token doesn't contain a `|` in it -- why not?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find the issue. Essentially I had implemented the `\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` interface incorrectly in my `User` class.

I had done this:

```
/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRememberToken() {
    return $this->remember_token;
}

/**
 * Set the token value for the "remember me" session.
 *
 * @param  string $value
 * @return void
 */
public function setRememberToken($value) {
    $this->remember_token = $value;
}
```

When I should have did this:

```
/**
 * Get the password for the user.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return $this->getAttribute('password');
}

/**
 * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getReminderEmail() {
    return $this->getAttribute('email');
}

/**
 * Get the token value for the "remember me" session.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getRememberToken() {
    return $this->getAttribute('remember_token');
}
```

I'm not sure where I copied that original code from, but essentially all the necessary data was stored in the model attributes, not on the class instance itself, so all those functions were returning `null` or an empty string.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this information! I was debugging non-remembering for hours, thanks to you I focused on my `getRememberToken()` and discovered a bug.